# Seemingly Pointless Regex Found in Code

Tags: java, regex, hibernate

So I inherited some code recently and looking through the code I found a regex that seems to allow pretty much any string. The regex is:

`^(?=\\s*\\S).*$`

This is on a field that will be saved to the database so my only thought is that maybe its doing some basic SQL injection protection. Thoughts? From what I can tell we are checking that there is a start\end of line, we have a positive lookahead for any white space or non-white space character, and we are allowing all characters.

Comment: What is done with the regex? Because the first non-whitespace character (including prefixed whitespace) is excluded from the match, which might be another point of the regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
^(?=\\s*\\S).*$
```

This just says that there cannot be an `empty string`.There has to be one non space character.So string like `'   '` will not pass neither will `""`.

This is similar to `^.*\S.*$`.`lookaheads` are expensive so you can use this.

Comment: Yes.  It would be more clearly written as `".*\\S.*"` for use with `Matcher.matches()`, or simply as `"\\S"` for use with `Matcher.find()`.